# XSD schema multiple choice value

Tags: xsd, schema, xsd-validation

In my xsd schema I have enumeration for status field and if I have value like "New" or "Cancelled" it's correct.

But sometimes I wan't to mix this values and I have status like this "New,Cancelled"

It's possible to handle this issue using only schema xsd without changes in application code ?

```
    <element name="status" type="tns:TStatus" maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="scheduledDate" type="dateTime" maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="0">
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<simpleType name="TStatus">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="New"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="Cancelled"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="Completed"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="Suspended"></enumeration>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Comment: No, that's impossible.

Comment: The predefined "list" type you could derive from your `TStatus` type would allow you to use a space separated list like e.g. `New Cancelled`, not a comma separated list.